# Traversing up the DOM and removing a class

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-traversal

I have several forms on a page, each form has it's own "message box" that displays the validation error. Each "message box" has a close button. I have no issue getting the close button to close the "message box" but I also need it to remove the class "error" from the offending text input. The page content is brought in by ajax, hence the ".on"

Pseudo HTML (remember there are at any time 8 of these all wrapped in their own form tag, which the message box and closing button are part of.

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="Form6">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="foo">label</label>
            <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
            <input type="submit" id="Button6" value="submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Msg6" class="error"><a class="close">X</a><ul></ul></div>
</form>
```

My attempt

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.close', function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).closest('input[type="text"].error').removeClass('error'); // doesn't work
    $('a.close').closest('ul > li > input.error').remove();// doesn't work
    //console.log($.closest('input[type="text"].error'));//tring to log the value of the ancestor
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(this).parents('form').find('input.error').removeClass('error');
```

But if you want to remove it, no need to change the class, just use `.remove()`...

Comment: perfect. so you traverse up the DOM to the parent form, then find the input.error and removeClass. Lesson learned sir. Just using remove to get a baseline, intention is to remove class.

Comment: yes, but you could use `closest` instead of `parents` too. I think it's faster because `closest()` will travel backwars until a match is found, while `parents()` will gather all parents, and then look for the match